# Error while compiling an embedded SpiderMonkey program

Tags: javascript, c++, static-libraries, header-files, spidermonkey

Alright, so I downloaded the SpiderMonkey source code using the command `wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js185-1.0.0.tar.gz` and extracted it. Then I successfully built the include files and static library by executing the following commands:

1. `autoconf2.13`
2. `./configure --prefix=~/js --disable-shared-js`
3. `make`
4. `make install`

Now I tried compiling the following code using the command `g++ -I/home/aaditmshah/js/include/js -L/home/aaditmshah/js/lib -lmozjs185-1.0 -ldl -lm -ldl helloworld.cpp -o helloworld`:

```
/*
 * This define is for Windows only, it is a work-around for bug 661663.
 */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# define XP_WIN
#endif

/* Include the JSAPI header file to get access to SpiderMonkey. */
#include "jsapi.h"

/* The class of the global object. */
static JSClass global_class = {
    "global", JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS,
    JS_PropertyStub, JS_PropertyStub, JS_PropertyStub, JS_StrictPropertyStub,
    JS_EnumerateStub, JS_ResolveStub, JS_ConvertStub, JS_FinalizeStub,
    JSCLASS_NO_OPTIONAL_MEMBERS
};

/* The error reporter callback. */
void reportError(JSContext *cx, const char *message, JSErrorReport *report)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u:%s\n",
            report->filename ? report->filename : "<no filename=\"filename\">",
            (unsigned int) report->lineno,
            message);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    /* JSAPI variables. */
    JSRuntime *rt;
    JSContext *cx;
    JSObject  *global;

    /* Create a JS runtime. You always need at least one runtime per process. */
    rt = JS_NewRuntime(8 * 1024 * 1024);
    if (rt == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* 
     * Create a context. You always need a context per thread.
     * Note that this program is not multi-threaded.
     */
    cx = JS_NewContext(rt, 8192);
    if (cx == NULL)
        return 1;
    JS_SetOptions(cx, JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX | JSOPTION_JIT | JSOPTION_METHODJIT);
    JS_SetVersion(cx, JSVERSION_LATEST);
    JS_SetErrorReporter(cx, reportError);

    /*
     * Create the global object in a new compartment.
     * You always need a global object per context.
     */
    global = JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject(cx, &global_class, NULL);
    if (global == NULL)
        return 1;

    /*
     * Populate the global object with the standard JavaScript
     * function and object classes, such as Object, Array, Date.
     */
    if (!JS_InitStandardClasses(cx, global))
        return 1;

    /* Your application code here. This may include JSAPI calls
     * to create your own custom JavaScript objects and to run scripts.
     *
     * The following example code creates a literal JavaScript script,
     * evaluates it, and prints the result to stdout.
     *
     * Errors are conventionally saved in a JSBool variable named ok.
     */
    char *script = "'Hello ' + 'World!'";
    jsval rval;
    JSString *str;
    JSBool ok;
    const char *filename = "noname";
    uintN lineno = 0;

    ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, global, script, strlen(script),
                           filename, lineno, &rval);
    if (rval == NULL | rval == JS_FALSE)
        return 1;

    str = JS_ValueToString(cx, rval);
    printf("%s\n", JS_EncodeString(cx, str));

    /* End of your application code */

    /* Clean things up and shut down SpiderMonkey. */
    JS_DestroyContext(cx);
    JS_DestroyRuntime(rt);
    JS_ShutDown();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that my `include` and `linker` options point to the correct directories. The include files are in `/home/aaditmshah/js/include/js` and the static library named `libmozjs185-1.0` is in `/home/aaditmshah/js/lib`. However it still produces the following error:

```
helloworld.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
helloworld.cpp:74:20: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
helloworld.cpp:83:17: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
/tmp/ccUU9may.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `JS_Init'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `JS_NewContext'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `JS_SetOptions'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `JS_SetVersion'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `JS_SetErrorReporter'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `JS_InitStandardClasses'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `JS_EvaluateScript'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `JS_ValueToString'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `JS_EncodeString'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `JS_DestroyContext'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `JS_Finish'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `JS_ShutDown'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x10): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x18): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x20): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x28): undefined reference to `JS_StrictPropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x30): undefined reference to `JS_EnumerateStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x38): undefined reference to `JS_ResolveStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `JS_ConvertStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x48): undefined reference to `JS_FinalizeStub'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I wonder which files am I missing. Should I rebuild SpiderMonkey and install it in `/usr/local`? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm pretty sure that the problem's not that I'm using a static library. I rebuilt SpiderMonkey as a shared object library and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, but that worked fine for me. I get both of the C++ warnings, but no linker errors. The resulting executable runs fine. I'm on a Mac. You might want to look at the output of `nm libmozjs185-1.0.a | grep JS_NewContext`. I get a line that says `00000000000016d0 T _JS_NewContext`.

Comment: I get a line that says `0000000000003500 T JS_NewContext`, which I assume means that `JS_NewContext`has a value of `13568`. I'm not sure what to make of this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
g++ -I/home/aaditmshah/js/include/js /home/aaditmshah/js/lib/mozjs185-1.0.a -lm -ldl helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

ie. add the archive directly in the g++ command line. You might need to specify some combinations of these if it is not working. (With gcc 4.2 this worked for me):

```
-static -lmozjs185
```

Just specify the correct path for mozjs185-1.0.a.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. What do the options `-lm` and `-ldl` mean? I'm using g++ version `g++-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.10, g++ version gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) and SipderMonkey v1.8.5: The command is`sudo g++ -o helloworld -I /usr/local/include/js helloworld.cpp -lmozjs185-1.0 -L /usr/local/lib -lpthread` Spend more than expected time doing something so simple sigh! No thanks to FireFox/Mozilla.